# plugins to do columnizing and paginating the web content

Tags: jquery-plugins

Hi i need to columize the web content like newspaper, kindly suggest for css propery  would work in IE browsers, or any one can suggest any plugins to do  columnizing   and paginating  the web content.

Answer (score 0):

Currently IE doesn't support any CSS for newspaper columns. IE 10 will however:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

jQuery plugins to replace it can easily found with a web search:

https://www.google.de/search?q=jquery+newspaper+columns